# Swagger UI Not Displaying Any Content On index.html Page solution for WebAPI TextToSpeech

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am creating TexttoSpeech Web API. Somehow swagger is not showing any content for the index page:
here is index page coding:

```
  @model TextToSpeechApp.Models.SpeechModel

  @{ViewData["Title"] = "Html-Page"; }

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body id="MasterBody" data-section="Articles">
 <form asp-controller="home" asp-action="/Index.chtml" method="post">
    <div>

        <h1>Test to Speech</h1>
        <div>


            <label asp-for="languague code"></label>
            <select asp-items="Model" class="dt" dt-default dropdown-           toggle id="" asp-fpr="languageCode"> </select>
        </div>
        <texttarea asp-for="Content" row="10" col="40"></texttarea>
        <button type="submit" class=""> Convert</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-"></div>
    <label class="Control-label">play voice</label>

    <audio controls>
        <source src="@Url.Action("translate","home",new {token= ViewBag-Context,Context=ViewBag-Context,lang=ViewBag})" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>

</form>
```

I have created a Speech Model as per below:

```
namespace TextToSpeechApp.Models
{
    public class SpeechModel
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public string SubscriptionKey { get; set; } = "< Subscription Key >";

        [DisplayName("Language Selection :")]
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; } = "NA";

        public List<SelectListItem> LanguagePreference { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "NA", Text = "-Select-" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "en-US", Text = "English (United States)"  },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "en-IN", Text = "English (India)"  },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "ta-IN", Text = "Tamil (India)"  },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "hi-IN", Text = "Hindi (India)"  },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "te-IN", Text = "Telugu (India)"  }
        };
    }
}
```

HTTPMethod request for post :

```
namespace TranslateTextApp.Business_Layer
{
    public class TranslateTextService : ITranslateText
    {/// <summary>/// Translate the given text in to selected language./// </summary>/// <param name="uri">Request uri</param>/// <param name="text">The text is given for translation</param>/// <param name="key">Subscription key</param>/// <returns></returns> 
        public async Task<string> Translate(string uri, string text, string key)
        {
            System.Object[] body = new System.Object[] { new { Text = text } };
            var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
                request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An interface is created on Startup page :

```
namespace TranslateTextApp.Business_Layer.Interface
    {
        interface ITranslateText
        {
            Task<string> Translate(string uri, string text, string key);
        }
    }
```

I followed the below link TextToSpeech and exactly did the same but No output is not showing
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-text-to-speech-in-multiple-languages-using-asp-net-core-c-sharp/

Comment: can you share the controller code? make sure each controller action method is explicitly  decorated with HTTP verb like HTTPGet[] or HTTPPost

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Refer to above code HTTPMethod request for post :                                              namespace TranslateTextApp.Business_Layer
{
    public class TranslateTextService : ITranslateText

Comment: is it from controller ?

Comment: yes , added this code in homeController as given in the link below https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-community-s-z/tree/master/Translate%20Text%20into%20multiple%20languages%20using%20Asp.Net%20Core%20&%20Csharp

Comment: I am following the link. Am I missing anything ?https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-text-to-speech-in-multiple-languages-using-asp-net-core-c-sharp/

Comment: have you explicitly decorate each actionmethod with httpget or http post?

Comment: Can I get your email ? so I can send my project to you If I missed anything.

Comment: you may add to GitHub and share link

Comment: @Laxmikant Thanks for help! here is Github link, https://github.com/dotnetexpo/TextToSpeechAPP